# JavaScript objects reference

Tags: javascript

I have a code:

```
function abc(){
    var dogs = {
      Fido: "Mutt",  Hunter: "Doberman",  Snoopie: "Beagle"
    };
    var myDog = "Hunter";
    var myBreed = dogs[myDog];
    console.log(myBreed);
}
```

myBreed has a value of Doberman. Next, I want to know how did var myDog = "Hunter"; could refer to the dogs property whereas in declaration I stated that it's a string?

Answer (score 1):

See [the specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-object-type):

> Properties are identified using key values. A property key value is either an ECMAScript String value or a Symbol value. All String and Symbol values, including the empty String, are valid as property keys. A property name is a property key that is a String value.

Object literal syntax allows you to use identifiers instead of strings, but they are converted to strings for the actual property name.